# merge mutiple images into a single pdf file and upload to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to merge multiple images into a single pdf file and upload this pdf file into firebase storage.
Current I can take multiple images using expo ImagePicker,

```
const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

const pickImageOnly = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 0.5,
    });
    
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage((images) => images.concat(result.uri));
    }
  };
```

For example, if I capture two picture using pickImageOnly, here is my console log to merge two URI into a single array:

```
Array [
  "file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Ftesting-app-6013c763-cab8-4d73-b64b-158393dfc677/ImagePicker/0300a01c-8818-4c1d-8fd8-6e3df043b3bc.jpg",
  "file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Ftesting-app-6013c763-cab8-4d73-b64b-158393dfc677/ImagePicker/eb2636cd-0912-4799-91db-e03dededdec1.jpg",
]
```

Now, I am struggling to convert this array list to a pdf file and upload it to firebase storage.

Comment: You've got multiple questions in one and the two tasks are unrelated. It's a good idea to stick to one question in your question to avoid super lengthy answers. Also, your Firebase uploading code is missing from the question. I would suggest narrowing the question to one and then open a second question for the other, ensuring you include your code.

Comment: Why do not you save each image to the firestore ?

Comment: This is our team requirement.